# Ruby On Rails Basic Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails by playing around with stuff and I'm attempting to play around with Grit. However I am a bit confused coming from a PHP background where I get the repo stuff from. My code

```
class RepoController < ApplicationController
  require "grit"
  repo = Grit::Repo.new("blahblahblah")

  def index()
    puts YAML::dump(repo)
  end

  def show()
    repo.commits('master', 10)
    puts repo.inspect
  end
end
```

I am trying to dump out information on the objects, but I cannot seem to access the repo variable. My IDE and Ruby keep saying `undefined local variable or method repo'` and I don't know why it cannot access the repo variable, it's declared at the top of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got scope problems. Try:

```
require 'grit'

class RepoController < ApplicationController
  def repo
    @repo ||= Grit::Repo.new("blahblahblah")
  end

  def index()
    puts YAML::dump(repo)
  end

  def show()
    repo.commits('master', 10)
    puts repo.inspect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your repo variable is being defined out of the scope that that is visible in your index and show actions. Probably what you want is something like this:

```
class RepoController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_repo  

  def index()
    puts YAML::dump(@repo)
  end

  def show()
    @repo.commits('master', 10)
    puts @repo.inspect
  end

  def set_repo
    @repo = Grit::Repo.new("blahblahblah")
  end
end
```

That creates an instance variable when the controller is loaded. Additionally you will want to get that require statement out of there and put gem "grit" in your Gemfile instead.